# Can anyone help me in handling ties in a python list while I try to replace it's elements with their ranks?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list that looks something like this:

```
lst_A = [32,12,32,55,12,90,32,75]
```

I want to replace the numbers with their rank. I am using this function to do this:

```
def obtain_rank(lstC):
    sort_data = [(x,i) for i,x in enumerate(lstC)]
    sort_data = sorted(sort_data,reverse=True)
    result = [0]*len(lstC)
    for i,(_,idx) in enumerate(sort_data,1):
        result[idx] = i
    return result
```

I am getting the following output while I use this:

```
[6, 8, 5, 3, 7, 1, 4, 2]
```

But what I want from this is:

```
[4, 7, 5, 3, 8, 1, 6, 2]
```

How can I go about this?

Comment: What is `listC`?

Comment: It can be any list, I am defining a function there. In this case, while calling this function, you can just replace lstC with lst_A.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. In case, you are not already aware, please read https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html to understand `defaultdict` and `deque`

```
from collections import defaultdict, deque

def obtain_rank(listC):
    sorted_list = sorted(listC, reverse=True)
    
    d = defaultdict(deque)  # deque are efficient at appending/popping elements at both sides of the sequence.
    for i, ele in enumerate(sorted_list):
        d[ele].append(i+1)
    
    result = []
    for ele in listC:
        result.append(d[ele].popleft())  # repeating numbers with lower rank will be the start of the list, therefore popleft
    
    return result
```

---

#### Update: Without using `defaultdict` and `deque`

```
def obtain_rank(listC):
    sorted_list = sorted(listC, reverse=True)
    
    d = {}
    for i, ele in enumerate(sorted_list):
        d[ele] = d.get(ele, []) + [i + 1]  # As suggested by Joshua Nixon
    
    result = []
    for ele in listC:
        result.append(d[ele][0])
        del d[ele][0]
    
    return result
```

Comment: It's cool but I am not allowed to import anything to my file!

Comment: Those two functions are in-built in Python. They are not external packages.

Comment: I added the solution that doesn't use any imports. Logically the both the snippets operating in the same way.

Comment: You can replace the conditional to check if the key exists with `d[ele] = d.get(ele, []) + [i + 1]`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
def obtain_rank(a):
    s = pd.Series(a)
    return [int(x) for x in s.rank(method='first', ascending=False)]
#[4, 7, 5, 3, 8, 1, 6, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use 2 loops:

```
l = [32,12,32,55,12,90,32,75]

d = list(enumerate(sorted(l, reverse = True), start = 1))

res = []
for i in range(len(l)):
    for j in range(len(d)):
        if d[j][1] == l[i]:
            res.append(d[j][0])
            del d[j]
            break
print(res)

#[4, 7, 5, 3, 8, 1, 6, 2]
```